# Keyboard works in BIOS but not at windows 7 password screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, bios

I have a brand  new Asus motherboard with 16 GB DDR4 ram and i5 processor .

I use old HDD with windows 7. But I am not able to enter password as keybord is inactive at the windows 7 password screen. The numlock light goes off. However I am able to use the same keyboard at BIOS.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: It appears your motherboard is not compatible with drivers on HDD. To test, use Live Linux media to see if the keyboard can be used... you might even wish to *install* the Linux distro to the HDD, if it works.

Comment: I will try and that and keep you posted. Thanks

Comment: Thanks DrMoishe use live CD and worked. Then found that motherboard don't have win7 driver. Upgraded to win 10

Comment: It was the Windows 7 that didnt had drives, I had to switch to Windows 10 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Posting in case someone else arrives here. I had the same problem (Mouse and KB working in BIOS, but in Win7 mouse was OK but no KB). Eventually found this solution (on YouTube!) that worked for me:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvyQXaf7X6Y

In short, use the on-sceen keyboard to regedit the UpperFilters key for the following three registry entries to be "kbdclass":

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{4D36E96B-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Class{4D36E96B-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E96B-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}

Answer (score 0):

Does your mouse work in Windows? If so, unplug the keyboard and go into device manager and uninstall the keyboard. Reboot. Works?
Also, did the motherboard come with a disk of drivers? If so, and your mouse works, install those. Without keyboard attached. boot up and then attach keyboard.

Comment: Mouse didn't work in windows. I cant go to windows screen

Comment: How long have you waited in Windows before trying the keyboard? In the past, when cloning drives, I have left the machine in Windows for up to 20 minutes while it decides there is a keyboard or mouse attached and fixes itself.

Answer (score 0):

For me this meant (windows 10, keyboard works in bios, not in Windows) that my kids had played with it and turned on accessibility "filter keys" from the login screen...